# How to write a variable in query post?

Tags: php, wordpress

i do the following, but donesn't work. how to correct it? thank u.

```
<?php 
$cat_name =single_cat_title('');
query_posts('category_name='.$cat_name.'&posts_per_page=10');
?>
```

the $cat_name value can't deliver to query_posts. why?

if i using the following. how to write   **'category_name'      => $cat_name,** part. thank u

```
<?php
    $cat_name =single_cat_title('');
$args = array(
    'category_name'      => $cat_name,

    'order'    => 'ASC'
);
query_posts( $args );
```

Comment: According to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title the return value is `FALSE` if not found. That is the problem.

Comment: What do you actually want ? Do you want to get name of user current category when browsing?

Comment: yes.i want to transfer the cat name to query post. how do i do?

Comment: @bokw i put the code in category.php. so single_cat_title have a value.thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
<?php $args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'taxonomy' => 'category' );
      $categories = get_categories($args);

      foreach ( $categories as $category) { 

        $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'post', 
                        'posts_per_page' => '10', 
                        'tax_query' => array( array(
                                                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                                'field' => 'slug',
                                                'terms' => $category->slug) ) 
                    );  
        query_posts( $args );
       } ?>
```